# Remove notifications from Facebook Group

Tags: facebook

So Facebook new Groups came out and I decided to join a group that was very popular (very). Left a comment on a post then left for 15 minutes. Checked my mail and 10 notifications were seen! As I write this there are more notifications coming in !

Please is there a way to stop this ? I went into the Facebook Settings page but no luck there changing the notifications. Based on the popularity of this group, it may explode my mail or Facebook. Any methods/settings (other than leaving the group) I am missing ?

Comment: Doesn't the "Groups" section of http://www.facebook.com/editaccount.php?notifications have the right options?

Comment: @ChrisF I unchecked those `Replies to your discussion board post` .I found the options will post a write up unless someone else does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some new options.

[How do I edit my notifications for my groups?](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=18793)

> To change the notification settings
>   for a Group you’re a member of, go to
>   the Group and click the "Edit
>   Notifications" button on the top right
>   corner of the page.

source: [Facebook New Groups Design Help](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=18793)

Here is the current setup I have used.
[image]

On top of this on each post you make a comment on, you must click Unsubscribe so that you are not notified about it on Facebook every second.

This solved it for me. These are for new groups. I checked one of my old groups and it has not undergone this change. Any other tips feel free to comment.